# Create .exe from python with Tensorflow and Kivy

Tags: python, tensorflow, kivy, pyinstaller

I am trying to make .exe file from my main.py script. In my main.py file I use Kivy and Tensorflow.
I use Pyinstaller to do it like that:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

There is no problem with Kivy, but I have problem with Tensorflow:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow'.
```

I was trying to do:

```
pyinstaller --paths venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\
```

but it didn't solve mt problem. I also tried to use cx_freeze with this setup.py file:

```
from cs_freeze import setup, Executable
setup(name = "main",
      version = "0.1",
      description = "",
      executables = [Executable("main.py")])
```

but then I have a problem with Kivy:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'kivy.weakmethod'.
```

I would like to ask what is the best way to create a .exe file from python script which use both Kivy and Tensorflow.

To be honest I want to create an exe file from this tutorial: 
https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@faad/tensorflow-image-recognition-app-in-kivy

Best regards

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same problem. This is the best link I've found so far - http://bitbionic.com/2017/08/02/how-to-deploy-pyqt-keras-tensorflow-apps-with-pyinstaller/ - but I also think the Python version used has something to do with the issue. There's very little info out the regarding this particular combo of technologies.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem as follows.
first imported `from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules` in my .`spec`

After i change my Analysis from `hiddenimports = []` to `hiddenimports=collect_submodules('tensorflow_core')`

it' work to me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
`pyinstaller --onefile --paths=<path to venv site packages, e.g. U:\myPyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages> <path to main python script>`

So in your case `pyinstaller --onefile --paths=venv\Lib\site-packages main.py`

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in a mistake:  
ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow'.

Comment: Have you tried installing pyinstaller directly in your venv and then calling it from there? `<path to venv>\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --onefile --paths=<path to venv site packages, e.g. U:\myPyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages> <path to main python script>`